# Add contraint that checks sum

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, constraints

I'm trying to add a constraint to a table by checking that the sum of a value is < 100.

This is my schema:

```
  CREATE TABLE Works  (
     eid      INTEGER,
     did      INTEGER,
     pct_time INTEGER,
     PRIMARY KEY (eid,did),
     FOREIGN KEY (eid) REFERENCES Employee(eid),
     FOREIGN KEY (did) REFERENCES Dept(did)
  );
```

I need to check that the sum of pct_time for each eid is <= 100.

For example

```
eid --- did ---- pct_time
0 ----- a ------- 50
0 ----- d ------- 40
0 ----- c ------- 20
1 ----- a ------- 90
1 ----- b ------- 10
2 ----- d ------- 40
2 ----- a ------- 20
```

Here, it should have errored when I added the 3rd entry for eid 0 as the sum > 100.
It would have been fine for eid 1 and 2 as pct_time <= 100
How can this be done?

So far all I've done is

```
ALTER TABLE Works
ADD CONSTRAINT c1
CHECK SUM(pct_time) < 100
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a trigger for this. Make it check if `SELECT SUM(pct_time) FROM Works GROUP BY eid` has any values that will go over 100 after your insert. If it is the case, throw an error.

Are you familiar with triggers? What database system are you using?

EDIT:
Check out the documentation for triggers [here](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/sql-createtrigger.html). Basically what you want is something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Work_insert_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON Works
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_sum_work();
```

Then your `check_sum_work()` procedure will check if any SUM(pct_time) > 100.

[Here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) is the documentation for trigger procedures, take note of the `NEW` special variable which allows you to single out the element being inserted. So you'll want to `SELECT SUM(pct_time) FROM Works WHERE eid = NEW.eid` and see if that sum + `NEW.pct_time` is greater than 100.

This might sounds pretty complicated if you've never seen triggers before, but it's actually a pretty powerful mechanism that you'll learn to appreciate. :)

[Here](http://halisway.blogspot.com/2005/09/postgres-triggers.html) is another example of PostgeSQL triggers being used.

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with triggers. I'm using postgres.